Is it true for every case? 'The induced charges and inducing charges have the same magnitude but opposite in sign'

The electron at the farther end (A) of the rod might have less impact on the electrons in the sphere, meaning it may not affect the sphere's charges. For instance, if five electrons are sufficiently distant to not influence the sphere's electrons, doesn't that imply that the inducing charge has a magnitude of five charges greater than the charge induced? Therefore, the statement doesn't cover all scenarios, or am I mistaken?

Hi Petri and welcome to the Physics SE. To get an induced charge we normally ground the object and the induced charge is then the charge that flows to or from ground. In your example the induced charge is zero. All you are doing is polarising the object and the charge separation due to the polarisation is not the same as on your bar. The charge separation just has to be enough to cancel the electric field from the bar so the field inside the conductor is zero.
